# Video URL pathExtension find nil

Tags: ios, swift3

I am fetching all images and videos in array as PHAsset, then trying to get their URL. In next part of code I am trying to get URL path extension and in this line I am getting error. My code is give below:

```
var imagesAndVideos: PHFetchResult<PHAsset>!
let asset = imagesAndVideos!.object(at: indexPath.row)

func grabPhotos(){
let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()


let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]


fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType == %d || mediaType == %d",
                                         PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue,
                                         PHAssetMediaType.video.rawValue)

imagesAndVideos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: fetchOptions)
}

var ext:String!
var url:NSURL!

imgManager.requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: nil, resultHandler: {(asset: AVAsset?, audioMix: AVAudioMix?, info: [AnyHashable : Any]?) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            let myAsset = asset as! AVURLAsset

            url = myAsset.url as NSURL
            self.photoLibraryVideoUrl.append(url)
            let videoData = NSData(contentsOf : url as URL)
            self.videoDataArray.append(videoData!)
            })

        })

   ext = "."+url.pathExtension!
   self.nameArray.append(dateStringForFolder+ext)
```

It shows url is nil in this line:

```
ext = "."+url.pathExtension!
```

This error does not show every time. I think (ext = "."+url.pathExtension!) code is executing before url getting value. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`requestAVAsset` is an async function and closure is called once the execution is complete. So `ext = "."+url.pathExtension!` and `self.nameArray.append(dateStringForFolder+ext)` can be execute even before the execution of the `requestAVAsset` completion closure. You have to move your code inside the closure.

```
imgManager.requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: nil, resultHandler: {(asset: AVAsset?, audioMix: AVAudioMix?, info: [AnyHashable : Any]?) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        let myAsset = asset as! AVURLAsset
        url = myAsset.url as NSURL
        self.photoLibraryVideoUrl.append(url)
        let videoData = NSData(contentsOf : url as URL)
        self.videoDataArray.append(videoData!)
        ext = "."+url.pathExtension!
        self.nameArray.append(dateStringForFolder+ext)
    })

})
```